# SKSpriteNode showing up in iOS 8, not in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, xcode6

I have a SKSpriteNode named ship, it's created like so :

```
ship = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Spaceship"]];
ship.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:ship.frame];
ship.xScale = .5;
ship.yScale = .5;
ship.alpha = 1.0f;
ship.position = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height/2);
[self addChild:ship];
```

The ship shows up fine on the iOS 8 simulator and on my iPhone 5 running iOS 8, but is invisible on iOS 7.

In the update method I put these logs :

```
NSLog(@"Ship : %@", ship);
NSLog(@"Image : %@", ship.texture);
NSLog(@"Alpha : %.2f", ship.alpha);
NSLog(@"Parent : %@", ship.parent);
```

And I get this output :

```
Ship : <SKSpriteNode> name:'(null)' texture:[<SKTexture> 'Spaceship' (100 x 100)] position:{160, 284} size:{25, 25} rotation:0.00
Image : <SKTexture> 'Spaceship' (100 x 100)
Alpha : 1.00
Parent : <SKScene> name:'(null)' frame:{{0, 0}, {320, 568}}
```

Everything there seems to be in order, and this same log gets repeatedly called every update until the ship, which is not visible at all, flies off screen and code is called to remove it and everything else.

Without any user interaction, on iOS 8, what happens with the ship is it appears in the middle of the screen, moves up, then when it exits the frame the game is over. As far as I can tell, the exact same thing is happening on iOS 7, except the ship is invisible. The frame's correct, it responds to user interaction, it's just not showing up.

Comment: XCode 6 is in beta right now. It could possibly be an issue. Have you tried running the same code on XCode 5 with the iOS 7 simulator or a device?

Comment: That was it, didn't even think about that, thanks!

Comment: It would also be advisable to file a bug report with Apple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XCode 6 is in beta right now. It could possibly be an issue. You should try running the same code on XCode 5 with the iOS 7 simulator or a device.

Also, you can file a bug report with Apple [here](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/).